# Change the clock icon color in MUI TextField with type 'time'

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

```
<TextField
  id="endTime"
  label="End Time"
  onChange={onEndTimeChange}
  type="time"
  defaultValue="16:00"
  className={classes.textField}
/>
```

the attribute `'type="time"'` is what renders an icon that looks like a clock. I would like to change the color of the clock icon. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the [`TimePicker`](https://mui.com/components/time-picker/) in the lab package if you want to easily customize the component. The native time input is harder to style because of the [lack of support](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome#how_do_i_change_the_appearance_of_the_date_picker). The following change the icon to green for example:

```
<TextField
  sx={{
    '& input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator': {
      filter:
        'invert(78%) sepia(66%) saturate(6558%) hue-rotate(84deg) brightness(127%) contrast(116%)',
    },
  }}
  type="time"
  {...}
/>
```

The filter value is generated from [this codepen](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp). If you decide to use the `TimePicker`, then the code would look like this:

```
<TimePicker
  label="Basic example"
  components={{
    OpenPickerIcon: (props) => (
      <AccessTimeIcon {...props} sx={{ color: 'red' }} />
    ),
  }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS to hide the clock icon and use your own icon:

**Not tested on all browsers** but is should work with browsers that support `-webkit`

```css
input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  background: none;
 
}

input[type="time"]{
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="time"]:after{
  content: "";
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/6g2dgm0/1535322171.png);
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-size: contain;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="time" />
```

Comment: What would be the format to add this to a reactjs file? It is not liking it when I add it to my css classes.